# How can I Enable And Disable Ajax Rating Control on CheckBox Check In JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

How can I Enable And Disable Ajax Rating Control on CheckBox Check In JavaScript??

Currently I'm enabling and disabling Textbox on CheckBox Check In JavaScript in this way

```
function Del_Checked(DelEnabled) {
    var DelStatus = document.getElementById("<%= cb_foodDelStatus.ClientID %>");
    if (DelStatus.checked === true) {
        document.getElementById("<%= tb_DelTime.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("<%= tb_DelTime.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    }
}

onclick = "Del_Checked(this.checked);"  // Added this to Checkbox
```

Comment: Do you mean rating control from AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: Yes the rating control from AjaxControlToolkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the Read only attribute of Ajax Rating control through jquery as:

```
if($("#checkboxID").is(':checked'))
 $find("RatingBehaviourID").set_ReadOnly(true);
```

Comment: set behaviour id of rating control same as you use in jquery .find()....means $find("BehaviourId").set_ReadOnly(true);

Comment: <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server"  BehaviorID="RatingBhvrId1">

Comment: Thnak you. Using the BehaviourID Worked for me.
Please change the `RatingControlID` to `RatingBehaviourID` in the Code.